# Issue with Tablet 10.1" WXVGA and Tablet WSVGA 7"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have an activity that contains a *LayoutView* with a png as background to give a nice frame effect as the rest of the app, ad a listView loaded in this LayoutView .

I have tested the app with all screen sizes and resolutions profiles in the latest version of ADT and works fine with all screen, but with these configuration

**-Tablet 10.1" WXVGA mdpi**

**-Tablet WSVGA 7" mdpi**

**-Nexus 7 7.17" 800x1280 tvdpi**

the list exceed the frame of background PNG and looks horrible.

Others configurations (also with the same resolution but different density and vice versa) works.

To fix the issue I must increase the listView margins, but this cause issues with all the others configurations.

How could I solve this problem, without change the graphic design of the app?

edit

I have added a sample of the problem, the listView must remain in the black area but in the described situations exceed the area
[image]

The red area is a LinearLayout1 with inside another LinearLayout2 with a ListView, the margins are large because the vivid red area contains the frame of the png used as background of LinearLayout1

Comment: Can you post the screenshot?

Comment: I have update the question adding a sample screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would need to resize/modify your background image that match certain screen density. In android you have a choice between with these folders to store images.

drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-hdpi-v11, drawable-ldpi ,drawable-mdpi, etc. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

The Android O.S will try to to use the most appropriate image based on the hardware screen resolution. So see if making the image bigger/smaller helps with the listview for certain screen density.

Screenshots would definitely help if this is not the case :P

Comment: The problem is that the issue doesn't happen with a specific density but only in these situations, for example with mdpi 3.2" works fine, but with mdpi 10.1" get the issue. I have added a sample screenshot that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use same background for all screens and dpi.

In this case, it is hard to do it (I found the same problem).

There are some solutions:

1. Use ninepatch for the background.
2. Divide background into several areas, and don't use margin instead of view with static size, as below:

> ```
> <layout>
>   <view id="left" size="20dp" background="left.png" />
>   <imageview id="content" size="0dp" weight="1" background="center.9.png" />
>   <view id="right" size="20dp" background="right.png" />
> </layout>
> ```

By using this, the layout does not relate with screen and dpi.

Comment: I'm already using ninepatch for the background, I could try to divide background but I'm not sure that this could resolve the issue